# Evaluation of nested function in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, I've seen the code with exact the same logic (except my newbie errors) :

```
function foo(a){
    var t = 1;
    function(b){
        console.log(a+b+(++t));
    }
}

bar = foo(5);
bar(6);
bar(6);
```

what is output of first and second call of `bar` function going to be ?

Comment: `foo` contains no `return` statement. It will always return `undefined`.

Comment: If you want to know what a piece of JavaScript code does, just run it yourself. Why ask SO for something that takes like 3 seconds in a browser?

Comment: `function (` at the beginning of a statement is a syntax error.

Comment: line 3, vat instead of var, you need a return statement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H,
Seems like too many problems with your code.
maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
function foo(a){
 var t = 1;
 return function(b){
        console.log(a+b+(++t));
       }
}
var new1 = foo(5); 
new1(6);// will output 13
new1(6);// will output 14
```

anyway,
you can try it on online REPL to test the code yourself.
[ONLINE JS REPL](https://repl.it/languages/javascript)
or any modern browser dev tools (F12 on chrome -> console for example)

Comment: Or just use ctrl+shift+J to get an interpreter in your browser.

Comment: this is it, exactly, is it because scope of `t` continue after `var = new1=foo(5);` ?

Comment: Basically Yes!
Easier to understand this this way:
"foo" is kind of class .
"new1" is an object of type "foo". 
"t" is a member of that "new1" object. 
Every time new1(6) is called, it grabs the new1 (already constructed object), and runs the anonymous returned function (while "t" lifetime equals the "new1" lifetime ).
ES6, or Typescript makes this is easy to understand as it pure object oriented.
I hope this helps